# Siege command's output not stopping even after specifying the exact number of concurrent users

Tags: load-testing, stress-testing

I am new in using Siege load & stress testing tool.

When I run the command like the below one

siege -c10 http://somedomain.com

The output never stops scrolling even after 10 requests.
It keeps on going for few hundreds of hits.
It does not show any error messages.
Every time I have to manually stop the process by Ctrl+C.

Why is it like this?

I am using Siege 3.0.3 from CentOS 6.4.

Another question, does 'Siege' support HTTPS protocol?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With the usage of "-r and -t" the constant non stopping result scrolling now have stopped.

Still there are issues dealing with the HTTPS sites.

I have kept a separate question on that with many details.

Please answer there. Link given below.

[Siege tool not working with HTTPS sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399782/siege-tool-not-working-with-https-sites)

Thanks.