# Siege https error: HTTPS requires libssl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, https, openssl, siege

I am having trouble getting [siege](https://github.com/JoeDog/siege) to work with https. Running Siege 4.0.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with OpenSSL 1.0.2g preinstalled and libssl-dev 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.6.

**The errors**
When I run it, I get a lot of these errors:
`[error] HTTPS requires libssl: Unable to reach www.mysite.com with this protocol: Transport endpoint is already connected`

And a couple of these
`[error] descriptor table full sock.c:133: Too many open files`

Then finally
`libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work`
`[1]    18421 abort (core dumped)  sudo siege -t 5M -d1 -c200 -f urls-f1.txt`

**My research**
I found a couple of answers online for getting siege to work with https.  For example, [this thread on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399782/siege-tool-not-working-with-https-sites) that says "configure using the --with-ssl option. Additionally, the openssl development headers must be installed".

Perhaps the best source is the INSTALL file in [the siege package](http://download.joedog.org/siege/siege-latest.tar.gz) itself, which says:
To enable https, you must have ssl installed on your system.  Get the
latest version from http://www.openssl.org. AFTER ssl is installed,
then you have to configure siege to use it:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/some/dir --with-ssl=/ssl/install/dir
```

The openssl default installation is /usr/local/ssl. If you installed
openssl in that directory, then you would configure siege like this:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/some/dir --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl
$ make
$ make uninstall (if you have a previous version already installed)
$ make install
```

I tried all these suggestions and found a couple more which said the same. But still I am stuck with the errors shown above. Perhaps I missed something or the latest software or OS has an issue. The next section shows what I did to set up the machine.

**How I set up the machine**
I am using a new VPS on DigitalOcean with Ubuntu 16.04.1 preinstalled. After setting up an additional user, SSH access and firewall, this is what  I did to setup siege.

1. Update system
   `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade --show-upgraded`
2. Install GNU Compiler Collection
   `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
3. Install openssl development headers package
   `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`
4. Download siege and extract
   `wget http://download.joedog.org/siege/siege-latest.tar.gz`
   `tar -zxvf siege-latest.tar.gz`
5. Configure and install siege
   `cd siege-*/`
   find where openssl resides:
   `which openssl`
   use this info for the with-ssl flag
   `./configure --with-ssl=/usr/bin/openssl`
   `make`
   `sudo make install`

**My question**
Please help me to get siege working with https URLs. In answering this question, please know that I am quite new to Linux admin stuff, so details on what to do are much appreciated.

Comment: Did you get this working? running into similar issue, and following their wiki for the setup :S https://wiki.mikejung.biz/Siege

Comment: @kafka: yes I did get it working, see my answer below

Comment: thanks, i did try that but to no avail. turned out we were able to use HTTP urls instead so just went with that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out the `--prefix` was needed to link up the libraries in my system. Even though installing seems to work fine and without errors if you don't supply that info. I set the prefix to the directory that siege was installing to before I supplied the prefix. So the installation ended up in the same directory but now it works with https.

This worked for me:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-ssl=/usr/bin/openssl
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Answer (score 5):

Do a 'make clean' before 'make install' to remove objects compiled without ssl support:

1. cd siege-*/
2. sudo make clean
3. sudo make install

Comment: that's the one, make clean, the ./configure with the ssl params, then make install

Answer (score 0):

I first uninstalled whatever I had tried to install first, then I simply used Brew to install siege

```
brew install siege
```

and it worked out of the box